# How to get particular element by index of an array in elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Say I have this document stored.

#### exemplary data

```
{"name": "haris","projects": [{"title": "Splunk"},{"title": "QRadar"},{"title": "LogAnalysis"}]}

{"name": "khalid","projects": [{"title": "MS"},{"title": "Google"},{"title": "Apple"}]}

{"name": "Hamid","projects": [{"title": "Toyota"},{"title": "Honda"},{"title": "Kia"}]}
```

#### code for mapping

```
PUT index_name
{
   "mappings": {
      "iterations_type": {
         "properties": {
            "projects": {
               "type": "nested",
               "include_in_parent": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**My Question**: I want to get 2nd element of "projects" array against some specific name e.g "name": "khalid".

**What I tried so far:**
I am new to ES and I searched forums for the answer, some suggest to specify mapping of "projects" key. I tried that too and the issue I face is 
1. when I create empty index, specify the mapping first and then insert the data, I get an error like "reason": "object mapping ["projects"] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"
2. when I create empty index, insert data first and then specify the mapping, I get and error like ""reason": "index [<>] already exists"
ard for me to specify mapping for each field explicitly

Thanks in advance